# Software not available from update server when installing Windows 8.1 on Mavericks

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

I am trying to install Windows 8.1 on OS X Mavericks via Bootcamp. I have a Macbook Pro mid 2010 model.

I'm running Bootcamp assistant 5.1.0 (473).

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error message when the installer tries to download Windows support software:

[image]

Any ideas why?

Comment: On a Mid-2010 on Bootcamp 4.0.4 (437) running 10.7.5, I can download Windows 7 drivers. Could it a be a connectivity issue to Apple servers? I have installed Windows 8.1 on a MBP 2012 on Mavericks + 5.1 Bootcamp, which is slightly different than what you have. Is Windows 8.1 supported on your configuration? Please take a look at this as well - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5634

Answer (score 2):

You can try manually updating the software. [Here's a link that you can use](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1638). Be sure to follow the instructions.